# Bootstrap 3 collapse with javascript not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I'm using Javascript options for `collapse`, the toggle doesn't work. It only opens first time the panel.
This one works well - `$('#login').collapse('toggle')`
But I want to add more options like parent.

http://www.bootply.com/DFfPmKnDTd#

Comment: your demo is not working

Answer (score 1):

this code can be help...

```
$('#login').collapse({
    toggle : true,
    parent : '#accordion'
});
$('#c1').on('click', function(){
        $('#login').collapse('toggle');
    }
);
```

First you need to initiate collapse function and then make call to toggle it.
Then you need to initialize each collapse link.

Try using by using this code may be it can work for target link.

`$.each($('#accordion .accordion-toggle'), function(index, collapse_link)
    { 
        var $collapse = $('#collapse_element_id'+element_no); // you need to right here '#c'+element_id ( it will take #c1, #c2 , #c3 )

        $collapse.collapse({ 
            toggle : true, 
            parent : '#accordion' 
        }); 
        $(collapse_link).on('click', function(){ 
            $collapse.collapse('toggle'); 
        }); 
    });`

Comment: Thanks!! how can i initiate all the collapsable divs? i gave more than 20

Comment: what is $('#collapse_element_id') ?

Comment: it will be ids of each collapsible elements in your case each 20 elements. (#c1,#c2,#c3) see edits .

Comment: hey friend I found something for you this can be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207238/javascript-toggle-with-bootstrap-collapse-plugin   :-)